# Class number 1 equal to UFD

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I think everyone assume that it is very obvious, but actually I do not see why the following statement is obvious:

> Class number 1 is equal that we have a UFD

So I tried to prove this for me:

$\rightarrow$ Class number 1 means every fractional ideal is a fractional principal ideal, so we have a PID and hence a UFD.

$\leftarrow$ We have a PID so a unique factorization into prime elements/ideals. And now I do not see how to go on.

Any suggestions? I hope it is not to obvious...

Comment: In a Dedekind domain, UFD and PID are equivalent. It can be proved that algebraic integers in a field is a Dedekind domain. You can consult any book on algebraic number theory for a proof.

Comment: Okay, that was easy, thanks :)

Comment: Of course there are UFDs which are not Dedekind domains, and need not be PIDs.